# MySQL: How to join 2 tables (a & b = x1) with Left join and 2 (c & d = x2) with Right join and then inner join them (x1 & x2)?

Tags: mysql, sql

A question requires that to happen, please assume:

```
a.ida = b.idb and c.idc = d.idd
and x1.id_i = x2.id_ii
```

a = customer

> #it contains the list of all the customers ever to have dined

b = waiter

> #it contains the list of waiters who served which customers

c = menu

> #just a simple menu, contains the index to all the food items

d = order

> #it is like the receipt, it has details like what was ordered and a reference to the waiter

Here is how I attempted it

```
SELECT x1.param1, x2.param1
FROM customer, waiter, menu, order
LEFT JOIN waiter ON customer.id = waiter.serve_id AS x1
RIGHT JOIN order ON menu.dish_index = order.dish_id AS x2
```

Now I want to have an inner join of all x1 and x2, the Table Order contains waiter_id which is equal to waiter.id, so is there any way to join x1 and x2?
Please help

Comment: Can you please include some sample data as formatted text along with some expected output?

Comment: I have added all the relevant details, since I am an assistant (training) and the question is on the internet I can't add all the details as the students just google the question. I very sincerely apologize for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `left join`s.  But you seem to be describing:

```
from (a left join
      b
      on <join conditions for a and b>
     ) join
     (d left join
      c
      on <join conditions on d and c>
     )
     on <join conditions for inner join>
```

Comment: after the on <join conditions for a and b>  can I type " AS x1" to give it an alias?

Comment: @RealSlimShady . . . No.  You would have to use a subquery (or CTE) if you want the results of a `join` to have an alias.

Comment: What would <the join conditions for inner join> be ? You said we cant give them aliases then how do I specify the column names (not a.col1 = c.col1)

Comment: @RealSlimShady . . . You can give aliases to the original tables, not to the result of the `JOIN` (unless you use an explicit subquery).  So there is no issue with subqueries.  Your original question didn't have column names, but the names are whatever you want for the inner join.